# How to format dictionary?

Tags: python, pprint

I have this function:

```
def total_fruit_per_sort():
    number_found = re.findall(total_amount_fruit_regex(), verdi50)
   
    fruit_dict = {}
    for n, f in number_found:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)
        
    return pprint.pprint(str( {value: key for value, key in fruit_dict.items() }).replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("'", ""))


print(total_fruit_per_sort())
```

But it prints the values like:  `'Watermeloenen: 466, Appels: 688, Sinaasappels: 803'`

But I want them under each other, like this:

```
Watermeloenen: 466
Appels: 688
Sinaasappels: 803
```

Question: how to archive this?

Comment: A first step could be to "fake" a recursive structure on your data such that `pprint` will provide more customization options: `l = list(d.items()); l.insert(0, l); pprint(l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some ways, the issue is that you are passing a `string` to `pprint` which has already been formatted.

Maybe add `.replace(',' , '\n')` at the end of the string before printing?

---

Using `pprint`, I think this would be the best way to format the dictionary (`D`):

```
print(pprint.pformat(D,width=1)[1:-1].replace('\n ','\n').replace("'",'').replace('"','').replace(',',''))
```

But I guess a direct one-liner `for-loop` looks nicer:

```
print('\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in D.items()))
```

Comment: Oke, thank you. It was more that I didn't understand why pprint didn't worked

Comment: Oke, But How to make it work with pprint? because if I do this: return (pprint.pprint( {value: key for value, key in fruit_dict.items() })) that doesn't work

Comment: #C-3PO thank you. But the problem with this is that the first item is a little bit to the right. So not in line with the other items.  But it is oke.

Comment: Hi, I think the last code using `pprint` gives the desired output. It is a bit messy, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `pprint` for this

```
result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in your_dict.items())
```